# graph theory,number of edges

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G_n$ be the graph with vertex set all binary strings of length $n$ (binary strings are strings of zeros and one, for example $0110100$ is a binary string of length seven). Two strings are adjacent if and only if they diﬀer in exactly three positions. What is the number of edges of $G_n$ as a function of $n$?

Comment: Do you have some context of this question, where do you study it? What are your thoughts on the problem what have you tried? What tools do you have avalible to you?

Comment: for example C9; the vertex 100000000 is linked to 000000000 by the path

000000000→011100000→010010000→100000000 .However,I can not go further

Answer (score 2):

Note $|G|=2^n$ and $G$ is $\binom{n}{3}$-regular. Then $$2\cdot e(G)=\sum_{v\in V} d(v)=\sum_{v\in V} \binom{n}{3}=2^n\binom{n}{3}$$

So $e(G)=2^{n-1}\binom{n}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate the number of edges coming out from any specific vertex, and remember that each edge has two vertices, then you can find out the solution pretty easily.